# A placeholder for "the entity" in Spring Data JPA custom queries

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

Suppose a number of my entities share a common attribute.

For each repository, I am writing a custom query to clear the entities based on that custom attribute.

```
public class EntityA {
    private ? commonAttr;
}

public class EntityARepository extends JPARepository<A,IDClass>{

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from EntityA where commonAttr : value")
    int deleteByCommonAttr(@Param("value") ? value)
}
```

Suppose the entities that share the same attribute are a dozen. Currently, I have to copy and paste the method in all repositories and replace `EntityA` with each entity I want to run the custom query on.

I would like to know if it is possible to replace the entity name with a placeholder in the `@Query` annotation.

This has the dual benefit that 1) if I have to copy&paste code, I can paste the fragment into all repositories without double-checking (equals fewer errors), and 2) I can try to create a super-repository interface for the entities that share a common attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data supports the use of Spring SPEL expressions in query definitions.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.x/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions

> We support the following list of variables to be used in a manual
>   query
>
> [*entityName*]
>
> `select x from #{#entityName} x`
>
> **Inserts the entityName of the domain type associated with the given
>   Repository**. The entityName is resolved as follows: If the domain type
>   has set the name property on the @Entity annotation then it will be
>   used. Otherwise the simple class-name of the domain type will be used.

Therefore:

```
public class EntityARepository extends JPARepository<A,IDClass>{

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from #{#entityName} where commonAttr : value")
    int deleteByCommonAttr(@Param("value") ? value)
}
```