# Loop through a list of spring flyway placeholders

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, migration, flyway

I have a list of strings and I want to loop through it and insert in the database based on those values.

Is it possible to have a list of values for spring.flyway.placeholders in order to loop through it in a sql script?

for ex:

```
spring.flyway.placeholders.values=[first, second, third]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A placeholder for "the entity" in Spring Data JPA custom queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359694/a-placeholder-for-the-entity-in-spring-data-jpa-custom-queries)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have access only on sql and properties/yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

First define your `placeholders` in your `application.properties` file like

```
spring.flyway.placeholders.first=FirstValue
spring.flyway.placeholders.second=SecondValue
spring.flyway.placeholders.third=ThirdValue
```

And in your `SQL migration script`, you can use these placeholders as follows:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (column_name) VALUES ('${first}');
INSERT INTO your_table (column_name) VALUES ('${second}');
INSERT INTO your_table (column_name) VALUES ('${third}');
```

However, if you want to loop through a `dynamic list` and `insert values` into the database based on that list, it's generally not possible in a `Flyway migration script` using placeholders, as SQL scripts are typically static.

Instead, you would typically use a programming language `(like Java or a scripting language)` to loop through the list and execute the necessary SQL statements.

Comment: Since I have access only on sql and properties/yaml files, I would have wanted to solve it this way but I will take into consideration your approach using Java. Thank you.